# error when importing jwcrypto in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, jwcrypto

I am using `jwcrypto` in python2.7, and here comes a problem.

```
>>> import jwcrypto 
>>> from jwcrypto import jwk, jws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lsq\.conda\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\jwcrypto\jwk.py", line 318
    raise InvalidJWKType(kty) from e
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not familiar with python2.7, and it seems like it is not allowed to use `raise from` in python2.7.

However, in `jwk.py` i found several `raise from` which cause the error above. I installed python2.7 via `conda create -n py27 python=2.7`, and installed `jwcrypto` via `pip install jwcrypto`.

Does anyone know how may this problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall 1.0 version and install 0.9.1 version for jwcrypto in python 2.7.

- pip install jwcrypto==0.9.1